# Does Agora.io for Unity provide these features?

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm a bit lost looking through all the various Agora.io modules (and not sure what it means that only some of them have Unity-specific downloads).

I want to make a Unity app where two remote phones exchange data as follows:

- Streaming voice in both directions
- Streaming video in one direction (recorded from device camera)
- Streaming a small amount of continuously-changing custom data in the other direction (specifically, a position + orientation in a virtual world; probably encoded as 7 floats)

The custom data needs to have low latency but does not need reliability (it's fine if some updates get lost; app only cares about the most recent update).  Updates basically every frame.

Ideally I want to support both Android and iOS.

I started looking at Agora video (successfully built a test project) and it seems like it will cover the voice and video, but I'm struggling to find a good way to send the custom data (position + orientation).  It's probably theoretically possible to encode it as a custom video feed but that sounds complex and inefficient.  Is there some out-of-band signalling mechanism I could use to send some extra data alongside/instead of a video?

Agora real-time messaging sounds like it would probably work for this, but I can't seem to find any info about integrating it with Unity (either on Agora's web site or in a general web search).  Can I roll this in somehow?

Agora interactive gaming could maybe also be relevant?  The overview doesn't seem real clear about how it's different from regular Agora video.  I suspect it's overkill but that might be fine if there isn't a large performance cost.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I would also consider alternatives to Agora if there's a better plugin for implementing this feature set in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agora's Video SDK for Unity supports exporting projects to Android, iOS, MacOS, and Windows (non-UWP).

Regarding your data streaming needs, Agora's RTM SDK is in the process of being ported to work within Unity. At the moment the best way to send data using the Agora SDK is to use [`CreateDataStream`](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/unity/classagora__gaming__rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine.html#aea9d5feeec22284b03a6546cf9d9f4b4) to leverage Agora's ability to open a data stream that is sent along with the frames. Data stream messages are limited to 1kb per frame and 30kb/s so I would be cautious about running it on every frame if you are using a frame-rate above 30fps.

Comment: Hermes, can this data stream send/receive a stream to/from a client using a web version of agora? I cannot find equivalent of CreateDataStream on the web SDK.

Comment: I should add that we want to send data between users on a group call with some users using the unity version and some using web.

Comment: The `dataStream` does not exist within the Agora Web SDK. To Be Honest it's not a stable way to send messages. The recommended way is using Agora's RTM SDK. The Unity version is currently under development.

Comment: The Agora RTM SDK is available for Android, iOS, macOS, and Windows so if you can't wait,  you could always wrap the SDK you need into a custom Plugin.